# Is McCree related to the Shimada clan in any way?

Tags: overwatch

I saw a comic strip claiming that McCree was a former leader of the Shimada Clan, is there something more into this or was the author simply mistaken/exploring non lore universe ?

Comment: and how does someone younger than the current Shimada Head oldest Son can be a former Shimada Head ?

Comment: @NamikazeSheena When one son is busy experiencing tranquility while the other is depressed because he thought he killed the first one ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, McCree has no relation with the Shimadas, besides being formerly on Overwatch alongside Genji.

What you were most likely reading was fanfiction.